# Vague Mechanical Turk Error Message

Tags: javascript, html, mechanicalturk

I keep getting an incredibly vague error message when trying to test out a mechanical turk HIT template.  I'm using mechanical turk's preview.  I've also tried uploading a batch of data and testing to no avail.

> There was a problem submitting your results for this HIT.

At first I thought this was a result of some invalid formatting on my part, but trying to submit data in the example template from the `Other` project type yields the same results.

Any ideas? Is there a way to get a more detailed traceback, or are there any common failure modes for Mechanical Turk that may produce this error message?

Are you even intended to be able to submit a mechanical turk HIT template in preview mode?

Comment: Haha, thanks for the sympathy? My life: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-1BJfDvSITY

Comment: MTurk expects you to send back an `assignmentId` plus some other fields to the correct URL. My guess would be you either misspelled (or miscapitalized `assignmentId`) or that you tried to post a sandbox HIT to the live server submit URL (or vice versa).

Comment: Hey Thomas, thanks for the response.  I'll have to check on how I'm handling the assignment id, but I'm this isn't an external question, so I assumed that was handled automagically.  I'm simply submitting the form that Mech. Turk wraps my custom css/javascript in.

Comment: Maybe update the question with some more details (e.g., the source code for the HIT, or a minimal version thereof) because that's a strange error to get using an HTMLQuestion.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon MTurk HITs seem to be printing a generic error message for a wide range of issues. This causes the problem to be particularity hard to debug.

For me, the error occurred since I was not assigning "name" attribute to my input elements in the form.

> You must include the HTML name attribute in the input field definition. Make your name attributes descriptive because they are used as the column headings in the Results table.

If you are using the GUI (at http://requester.mturk.com/) to build and deploy your tasks, I recommend giving this document a good read and see if you have missed something. In general, you'll want to give your input fields names to ensure you can reference them accurately when retrieving your results.

[MT Requester UI guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29814288/3567932)

Hope this helps.

> [Link to original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29814288/3567932)